# How to detect hold and fastforward event in react native TVEventHandler

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. I want to know how can implement press and hold event for seek.
I am able to get fastForward and press right events in React native layer by using below code.

```
_enableTVEventHandler() {
    this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {
      if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(2)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(1)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(0)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
        cmp.setState({board: cmp.state.board.move(3)});
      } else if(evt && evt.eventType === 'playPause') {
        cmp.restartGame();
      }
    });
  }
```

Not able to get the hold fastforward or hold and right event to detect seek event. I am not sure it if its possible in RN layer. If not then how can i do the same in Android layer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this where eventKeyAction is an integer value that represents button press(down/up).where "key up" is 1, "key down" is 0.
so you could use that to serve your purpose

```
const [isfastForwarding, setisfastForwarding] = useState(false);

 const _enableTVEventHandler = () => {
    _tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    _tvEventHandler.enable(this, (cmp, { eventType, eventKeyAction }) => {
      // eventKeyAction is an integer value representing button press(key down) and release(key up). "key up" is 1, "key down" is 0.
      if (eventType === "fastForward" && eventKeyAction === 0) {
        setisfastForwarding(true);
      }
      if (eventType === "fastForward" && eventKeyAction === 1) {
        setisfastForwarding(false);
      }
    });
  };
```

you can also add some delay if you wish to